# Adding items to an ImmutableList<T> inside an ImmutableDictionary<TKey, TValue>

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5, c#-8.0, immutable-collections

I can't seem to figure out how add items to an `ImmutableList` inside of an `ImmutableDictionary`.

I have the following variable:

```cs
ImmutableDictionary<string, ImmutableList<string>> _attributes = ImmutableDictionary<string, ImmutableList<string>>.Empty;
```

To which I'm trying to add a value inside of the list:

```cs
string[] attribute = line.Split(':');
if (!_attributes.ContainsKey(attribute[0]))
    _attributes = _attributes.Add(attribute[0], ImmutableList<string>.Empty);
if (attribute.Length == 2)
    _attributes[attribute[0]] = _attributes[attribute[0]].Add(attribute[1]);
```

However, I get an error saying that the `ImmutableList` doesn't have a setter. How do I replace the list in the dictionary without having to rebuilt the entire Dictionary?

Comment: Quite frankly it is unclear what do you want to achieve, but are you aware of the [ImmutableDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Builder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutabledictionary-2.builder) class and [ToImmutableDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutabledictionary.toimmutabledictionary) methods? These let you construct the collection and then make that immutable.

Comment: That make make my code more efficient... I'll look into that. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ImmutableCollections provide a bunch of different ways how you can construct them.
The general guidance is first populate them then make them immutable.

#### `Create` + `AddRange`

```cs
ImmutableDictionary<string, string> collection1 = ImmutableDictionary
    .Create<string, string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    .AddRange(
        new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("a", "a"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("b", "b"),
        });
```

We have created an empty collection then created another one with some values.

#### `Create` + `Builder`

```cs
ImmutableDictionary<string, string>.Builder builder2 = ImmutableDictionary
    .Create<string, string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    .ToBuilder();

builder2.AddRange(
    new[]
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("a", "a"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("b", "b"),
    });

ImmutableDictionary<string, string> collection2 = builder2.ToImmutable();
```

We have created an empty collection then converted it to a builder.
We have populated it with values.
Finally we have constructed the immutable collection.

#### `CreateBuilder`

```cs
ImmutableDictionary<string, string>.Builder builder3 = ImmutableDictionary
    .CreateBuilder<string, string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

builder3
    .AddRange(
        new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("a", "a"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("b", "b"),
        });

ImmutableDictionary<string, string> collection3 = builder3.ToImmutable();
```

This is short form of the previous case (`Create` + `ToBuilder`)

#### `CreateRange`

```cs
ImmutableDictionary<string, string> collection4 = ImmutableDictionary
    .CreateRange(new[]
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("a", "a"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("b", "b"),
    });
```

This is short form of the first case (`Create` + `AddRange`)

#### `ToImmutableDictionary`

```cs
ImmutableDictionary<string, string> collection5 = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "a", "a" },
    { "b", "b" }
}.ToImmutableDictionary();
```

Last but not least here we have used a converter.

Comment: this question/answer is under rated. Just 1/2 upvotes. Thanks!

Comment: @PedroCoelho Thanks for the upvote and I'm glad if you have found my post valuable.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was under my nose. Just like I need to call Add and overwrite the original variable when adding items, I need to call [SetItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutabledictionary-2.setitem?view=net-5.0) on the Dictionary. Makes sense!

Comment: No, you misunderstood it. `SetItem` is actually a factory method, which will create a **new immutable collection from the original where a given key is already updated with the specified value**.

Comment: No I understood it correctly, I just need to do: _attributes = _attributes.SetItem (attribute[0], _attributes[attribute[0]].Add(attribute[1]));

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`ImmutableDictionary.TryGetValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutabledictionary-2.trygetvalue) method, in order to reduce the dictionary lookups from 3 to 2.

```
var _attributes = ImmutableDictionary.Create<string, ImmutableList<string>>();

string[] parts = line.Split(':');
if (parts.Length == 2)
{
    string attributeName = parts[0];
    string attributeValue = parts[1];

    if (_attributes.TryGetValue(attributeName, out var list))
    {
        _attributes = _attributes.SetItem(attributeName, list.Add(attributeValue));
    }
    else
    {
        _attributes = _attributes.Add(attributeName, ImmutableList.Create(attributeValue));
    }
}
```

In case you wanted to update the dictionary with thread-safety as an atomic operation, you could use the [`ImmutableInterlocked.AddOrUpdate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutableinterlocked.addorupdate) method:

```
ImmutableInterlocked.AddOrUpdate(ref _attributes, attributeName,
    _ => ImmutableList.Create(attributeValue),
    (_, existing) => existing.Add(attributeValue));
```