# Is there a way to convert static string class property to Dictionary in C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary, constants

```
public static class somename
{
    public const string abc = "abc 1";
    public const string xyz = "xyz 2";
    public const string vhj = "vhj 3";
}
```

I wanted to convert this into *dictionary* object and use this in `foreach`

Any idea?

Comment: Since these are all compile time constants, why not just declare them as a dictionary in the first place, instead of as `const`s?

Comment: You mean manually or in code?

Comment: Sweeper means manually. You also can use reflection to access required static props and then you can iterate over them to build the Dictionary

Comment: ^^ Which should be done once and cached, if at all.

Comment: Are you looking for [`ImmutableDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutabledictionary-2?view=net-7.0)?

Comment: @PeterCsala Mind that `ImmutableDictionary` still has `Add` etc. You just get copies as result.

Comment: @Fildor Yes, exactly, but the original collection remains untouched. So it is indeed immutable.

Comment: @PeterCsala Yes, I was going for the API. I assumed OP is more going for something like [IReadOnlyDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlydictionary-2?view=net-7.0)

Comment: @Fildor you can use the combination of two as well :) Expose it as `IReadOnlyDictionary` and use `ImmutableDictionary` as the implementation.

Comment: @PeterCsala That sounds like a good plan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare a static readonly dictionary with an initializer, if that's what you mean:

```cs
public static readonly Dictionary<string, string> MyDict = 
    new Dictionary<string, string> {{"abc", "abc 1"}, {"xyz", "xyz 2"}, {"vhj", "vhj 3"}};
```

To generate it from the class you already have, you need to use reflection:

```cs
var constants = typeof(somename).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)
    .Where(fi => fi.IsLiteral && !fi.IsInitOnly && fi.FieldType==typeof(string));
var myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var c in constants)
{
    myDict.Add(c.Name, (string)c.GetRawConstantValue());
}
```

Comment: Mind that the "readonly" Dictionary _is still **mutable**_.

Comment: Yes, it is mutable. It's possible to only expose a ReadOnlyDictionary based on the dictionary, if you should wish to do so.

Comment: Don't get me wrong: That doesn't make the answer invalid. Just felt it was worth pointing out to OP.

Answer (score 2):

You can't create `const` dictionary, but you can do it `readonly`:

```
public static class somename {
  // We can't assign MyDictionary (readonly)
  // We can't add, remove or change items (IReadOnlyDictionary)
  public static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> MyDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
    { "abc", "abc 1" },
    { "xyz", "xyz 2" },
    { "vhj", "vhj 3" },
  };
}
```

I've exposed `IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string>` to prevent unwanted chageing like

```
somename.MyDictionary["abc"] = "pqr" // typo: `=` instead of `==`
```

If you want elaborated logic, you can put it into *static constructor*:

```
public static class somename {
  public static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> MyDictionary;

  static someone() {
    Dictionary<string, string> myDict = new();

    myDict.Add("abc", ComputeAbc());
    myDict.Add("xyz", ComputeXyz());
    myDict.Add("vhj", ComputeVhj());

    MyDictionary = myDict;
  }
}
```

You can enumerate `{Key, Value}` pairs in `foreach`, e.g.

```
foreach (var pair in somename.MyDictionary) {
  Console.WriteLine($"{pair.Key} == {pair.Value}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it was stated by many people on this thread you can't really map your static class with const fields to a dictionary with the same runtime guarantees. In order to understand the problem let's define three terms:

- **Const**: It has a compile-time guarantee that its value can't be changed.
- **Readonly**: It has a run-time guarantee that once it is initialized it can't be changed.
- **Immutable**: It has a run-time guarantee that whenever you perform a modification operation then it creates a new version of the object.

Please also bear in mind that objects and collections are treated in a different way. For example if you mark a collection as readonly it means you can't change the reference of the collection to another collection or to null. But it does not prevent you to add/remove items to/from the collection.

That's there are [`ReadonlyDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.readonlydictionary-2?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0) and [`ImmutableDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutabledictionary-2?view=net-7.0).

The closest thing what you can get is to use [`ImmutableDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutabledictionary-2?view=net-7.0) as an implementation and expose it as an [`IReadonlyDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlydictionary-2?view=net-7.0).

```
public readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> somenames = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "abc", "abc 1" },
    { "xyz", "xyz 2" },
    { "vhj", "vhj 3" }
}.ToImmutableDictionary();
```

There are several ways to build an immutable collections. [Here I have listed a couple of options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66015182/13268855).